# Powershell script to search, split and join in one line

Tags: regex, powershell

Been racking my Friday brain on a regex problem with dealing with Sql Server object names.

An input to my Powershell script is a procedure name. The name can take many forms, such as

```
dbo.Procedure
[dbo].Procedure
dbo.[Procedure.Name]
```

etc

So far I'd come up with the following to split the value into it's constituent parts:

```
[string[]] $procNameA = $procedure.Split("(?:\.)(?=(?:[^\]]|\[[^\]]*\])*$)")
```

In addition I have a regex that I could use to handle the square brackets

```
(?:\[)*([A-Za-z0-9. !]+)(?:\])*
```

And this is about as far as my limited regex experience will take me.

Now granted I could deal with a lot of this by treating each element in a **ForEach** and doing a RegEx replace there, but y'know that just seems so, I dunno, *ungainly*. So, question I have for any passing Powershell & RegEx guru:  **"How can I do all this in one line?"**

What'd I'm looking for is where I can get the following results

```
Original                 Corrected
=====================    =====================
dbo.ProcName             [dbo].[ProcName]
dbo.[ProcName]           [dbo].[ProcName]
[dbo].ProcName           [dbo].[ProcName]
[dbo].[ProcName]         [dbo].[ProcName]
[My.Schema].[My.Proc]    [My.Schema].[My.Proc]
[My.Schema].ProcName     [MySchema].[ProcName]
dbo.[ABadBADName!        [dbo].[[ABadBADName!]
```

(Notice the last instance where an object name starts *but does not end* with a square bracket (not that I'm expecting that [and if I saw anyone on my team naming an object like that I'd be asking HR if I can fire them for it], but I do like to be so thorough).

Think that covers everything...

So, over to you Powershell & RegEx gurus - how do I do this?

Please limit any answers to FULLY answering the question with code I can actually use and not just syntax suggestions.

**Clarification:** I am acutely aware that sometimes 'slow and steady wins the race' may apply here and that support wise it would be potentially safer to handle the rest in a ForEach, but that's not the point. Part of this is to help me understand just how flexible RegEx can be, so this is more of an educational exercise rather than a philosophical one.

Comment: Sound advice: don't try to be clever about this - your future self will hate you :-) 10 lines of well-structured code may seem boring and "ungainly", but a clever one-liner will be your worst nightmare one day

Comment: Well aware of that. I'm currently coding using the ForEach, but I'm fascinated as to the alternatives. Also, I've been in the game nigh on 30 years so my future self and present self are fast colliding and have multiple t-shirts bearing the same motto... :) But now it's a challenge!

Comment: Deleted my answer didn't read the whole story it seems :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay how about this:

```
@'
dbo.ProcName            
dbo.[ProcName]          
[dbo].ProcName          
[dbo].[ProcName]        
[My.Schema].[My.Proc]   
[My.Schema].ProcName    
dbo.[ABadBADName!       
'@ -split '\s*\r?\n\s*' | % {
    $_ -replace '^(?:\[(?<schema>[^\]]+)\]|(?<schema>[^\.]+))\.(?:\[(?<proc>[^\]]+)\]|(?<proc>[^\.]+))$', '[${schema}].[${proc}]'
}
```

Note that I'm only using `ForEach-Object` (`%`) here to iterate through your test cases; the actual replace is done with a single regex / replace.

## Explanation

So the important part here is the regex:

```
^(?:\[(?<schema>[^\]]+)\]|(?<schema>[^\.]+))\.(?:\[(?<proc>[^\]]+)\]|(?<proc>[^\.]+))$
```

Breaking it down:

- `^` -- match the beginning of the string
- `(?:` -- open a non-capturing group (for alternation purposes)

  - `\[` -- match a literal left bracket `[`
  - `(?<schema>` -- start a named capture group, with the name `schema`

    - `[^\]]+` -- match 1 or more of any character that is **not** a literal right square bracket `]`
  - `)` -- end the `schema` capture group
  - `|` -- alternation; if the previous expression didn't match, try what comes after this
  - `(?<schema>` -- again start a named capture group called schema; this is only tried if the other one didn't match.

    - `[^\.]+` -- match 1 or more of any character that is **not** a literal dot `.`
  - `)` -- end the alternate `schema` capture group
- `)` -- end the non-capturing group
- `\.` -- match a literal dot `.` (this is the one separating schema and proc)

  - (the next part for `proc` is exactly the same steps as above, with a different name for the capturing group)
- `$` -- match the end of the string

In the replace, we just qualify the names of the groups with `${name}` syntax instead of the numbers `$1` (which would work too actually).

Comment: Almost; however [dbo].[TestPSProc2 yields [dbo].[TestPSProc2] and not the expected edge case of [dbo].[[TestPSProc2]. That said, I find the answer most fascinating and am now happily digging in to what's going on!

Comment: @RachelAmbler I might have missed something, why would you want ` [dbo].[TestPSProc2` to yield `[dbo].[[TestPSProc2]`? Is the left square bracket in the proc supposed to be part of the name, and therefore escaped?

Comment: It's a huge edge case - and, TBH will never happen on my watch so, you know what, I'm gonna give it to you anyway. That said, if you could give me the final nudge regardless, even though I'm gonna accept your answer, then that would be really appreciated! So, yeah it is theoretically possible to have [[TestProc2] as  a valid (but evil and wrong on every level) name

Comment: @RachelAmbler I've updated it to work as expected. I was originally taking a shortcut in the second part, but given that clarification it's easier to just repeat the same steps for `proc` as for `schema`; explanation updated as well.

Comment: You sir, are a verifiable RegEx genius. Thank you SO much for helping me out. I'm going to spend quite some time delving into exactly what's going on now. Kudos!

Comment: @RachelAmbler check out [RegEx Storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester). You can paste the regex in there, and sample input; it even shows the replacements.